# is it possible to keep a packaged app running after `chrome.runtime.reload()` without additional windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a [packaged app](https://github.com/zebradog/kiosk) that calls `chrome.runtime.reload()`. On a desktop OS (Windows, OSX) this call will cause the application to close, but not restart unless there is an additional Chrome page open.

I assume this is because if it is the only Chrome app running, it closes the Chrome process entirely and there is nothing to restart it.

Adding the [`background` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions#background) looks like it should work, according to the documentation but it does not seem to actually start Chrome when the user logs in (and keep it running) as the documentation states.

Answer (score 0):

A user can override this globally with a setting.

In Chrome's settings with "Show advanced settings":

> System > Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed

Perhaps it is disabled on your development system.